Orthogonality of two projections in $\mathcal B(H)$
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal B(H)$ denotes the space of all bounded operators on $H$. For any projections $p,q \in \mathcal B(H)$ we define a projection from $H$ onto the closure of linear span of $p(H)\bigcup q(H)$ and denote the projection by $\sup (p,q)$. So clearly by definition $\sup(p,q)(H)=\overline{[p(H)\bigcup q(H)]}$.
Let $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are non-zero distinct projections in $\mathcal B(H)$. Let us now consider two projections $q$ and $r$, defined by
$$q=\sup(p_1,p_2)-p_1~\text{ and }~ r=\sup(p_2,p_3)-p_2.$$
I want to show that $qr=0$, that is $q$ and $r$ are orthogonal projections.
I started to show that $q(H)\bigcap r(H)=\{0\}$. For that let $0\ne \xi \in q(H)\bigcap r(H)$. This follows that $\xi \in q(H)$ and $\xi \in r(H)$. Now by the aforementioned definition, we have
$$\xi \in \overline{[p_1(H)\bigcup p_2(H)]}\bigcap \overline{[p_2(H)\bigcup p_3(H)]},~\text{but }~ \xi \notin p_1(H)\bigcup p_2(H),$$
where $p_1(H), p_2(H) $ and $p_3(H)$ are closed subspace of $H$. Please help me to solve this, I am unable to proceed from here. Thank you.

This is not true. For example, let $H = \mathbb{C}^2$, $p_1$ be the projection onto the span of $(1, 0)$, $p_2$ be the projection onto the span of $(1, 1)$, and $p_3$ be the projection onto the span of $(0, 1)$. Then $q$ is the projection onto the span of $(0, 1)$ and $r$ is the projection onto the span of $(1, -1)$, so they are not orthogonal.

It is true that $q(H) \cap r(H) = 0$, though. Any element of $q(H)$ has to be orthogonal to $p_1(H)$ and any element of $r(H)$ has to be orthogonal to $p_2(H)$, so it is orthogonal to $\sup(p_1, p_2)H$. But $q(H) \subset \sup(p_1, p_2)H$, so any such element must be $0$.

Thank you for this. Is there any way to construct such projections $ q$ and $r$ using $p_1, p_2,$ and $p_3$ so that $q$ and $r $ are orthogonal?

@DenOfZero What kind of properties do you want $q$ and $r$ to have? Like, do $q = \sup(p_1, p_2) - p_2$ and $r = p_2$ work?

In my case, how to show that $q(H)\cap r(H)={0}$?

@DenOfZero I already supplied a proof of that in my first comment.
